# decorator inside class with arguments for function that accept arguments

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I've found way to have decorator in class, to have decorator with args, to decorate function with args. But I can't make all of it work together. How can I make this work ?

```
class Printer():
    """
    Print thing with my ESCPOS printer
    """
    def text(self, text):
        with open('/dev/usb/lp0', 'wb') as lp0:
            lp0.write(text.encode('cp437'))
            lp0.write(b'\n')
    def command(self, command):
        with open('/dev/usb/lp0', 'wb') as lp0:
            lp0.write(command)
            lp0.write(b'\n')
    def style(command_before, command_after):
        """
        Send a command before and a command after
        """
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(self, text):
                print(self)
                print(text)
                self.command(command_before)
                func(text)
                self.command(command_after)
            return wrapper
        return decorator
    @style((b'\x1D\x42\x31'), (b'\x1D\x42\x32')) #print white on black
    @style((b'\x1D\x21\x34'), (b'\x1D\y21\x00')) #print bigger
    def title(self, title_text):
        self.text(title_text)
```

then I could use it that way:

```
p = Printer()
p.title('This is an awesome TITLE!!')
```

This give me a "*TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'*"

But I just fail to get it :/

Comment: is `style()` supposed to be a static method? You aren't passing in `self`

Comment: `style` only appears to be intended to be used inside the class definition; what the metaclass does with it once the class is defined doesn't appear to matter.

Comment: @chepner: Ah. I think I get it. :) Because `style` is used as a decorator while the class is being defined it's behaving like a normal (unbound) function, not a method, so it doesn't take a `self` arg. And that means we could move the definition of `style` outside of the `class Printer():` definition & it will still work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `func` needs to read `func(self, text)`. The reason is that in this case `func` is not yet a bound method to an instance.

That is not possible at the time the class is created. There is no instance that you could bound it to. So `func` in your wrapper function is just a plain function and hence needs the same arguments as you defined it with

```
def title(self, title_text)
    ...
```

I changed the example like this

```py
class Printer():
    """
    Print thing with my ESCPOS printer
    """
    def text(self, text):
#         with open('/dev/usb/lp0', 'wb') as lp0:
#             lp0.write(text.encode('cp437'))
#             lp0.write(b'\n')
        print('Text', text)

    def command(self, command):
#         with open('/dev/usb/lp0', 'wb') as lp0:
#             lp0.write(command)
#             lp0.write(b'\n')
        print('Command', command)

    def style(command_before, command_after):
        """
        Send a command before and a command after
        """
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(self, text):
#                 print(self)
#                 print(text)
                print('type of func', type(func))  # see that it is not bound
                self.command(command_before)
                func(self, text)  # <-- use (self, ...)
                self.command(command_after)
            return wrapper
        return decorator

    @style((b'\x1D\x42\x31'), (b'\x1D\x42\x32')) #print white on black
    @style((b'\x1D\x21\x34'), (b'\x1D\y21\x00')) #print bigger
    def title(self, title_text):
        self.text(title_text)
```

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thanks for the hint. I should have look more carefully.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was lookin for :) and the explaination I was lookin for

Answer (score 3):

`func()` in your decorator is still an unbound function. You need to bind it explicitly or pass in `self` explicitly:

```
# bind it to self
func.__get__(self)(text)

# or simply pass in self directly
func(self, text)
```